# Date '% {syslog_timestamp} ' is not recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I'm getting an error upon attempting to SELECT anything from a particular table that reads: "Date '%  {syslog_timestamp} ' is not recognized".

Per [this Snowflake forum post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000099Vj5wSAC/date-format-not-recognized), I tried running my SELECT query with TO_DATE('2021-02-17','YYYY-MM-DD') and this worked but I'm not entirely sure why... **syslog_timestamp** is not a column in the table, and does not show up as a parameter upon running SHOW PARAMETERS or as a variable upon running SHOW VARIABLES. Can anyone tell me what syslog_timestamp is or where it might be coming from?

Comment: Can you try `select column_whatever from your_particular_table order by 1` and in `desc` order to see what the data has? Share more of this problem setup too please

Comment: Looks like the issue is probably your data rather than your SQL. The column that you're selecting from seems to have some bad data in it (`'% {syslog_timestamp} '`) as alluded to by Felipe

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I ran the command you suggested but I got the same error. I will investigate the upstream data and if I find that that is not the cause I will provide more setup info.

Comment: I think @SimonDarr might be right about it being bad data though. I hadn't considered it before, but the %{field} is Jinja2 formatting which is used in our upstream parsers. Will let y'all guys know. Thank you for the responses thus far.

Comment: Correction: %{Field} is not Jinja2 formatting, it's Logstash formatting.

Comment: Yeah it looks like something that your app is spitting out rather than an error from Snowflake itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of bad data. Our upstream Logstash parsers were outputting the literal value "%{field}" in some cases because the value did not exist in all the incoming data records.